# How to combine 2 JSON objects into one with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON objects in two files (result_0.json and result_1.json) which look like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "pools": [
      {
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pools": [
      {
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I would like to get looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pools": [
      {
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can it be done? I tried

```
jq -s add result_0.json result_1.json
```

but it just overwrites the values in result_0.json with the values of result_1.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.data` and `.pool` are the only keys in the json files, you can use

```
jq -n '{ data: { pools: [inputs.data.pools] | add } }' result0 result1
```

This will create the desired output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "pools": [
      {
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "id": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

Regarding the `inputs` keyword, consider reading [JQ's docs on this part](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#inputs).